# What does it mean that there is faster failure with atomic grouping

Tags: regex, pcre

**NOTE** :- *The question is bit long as it includes a section from book.*

I was reading about `atomic groups` from [Mastering Regular Expression](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124).

It is given that `atomic groups` leads to **faster failure**. Quoting that particular section from the book

> > **Faster failures with atomic grouping.** Consider `^\w+:` applied to
> >     `Subject`. We can see, just by looking at it, that it will fail
> >     because the text doesn’t have a colon in it, but the regex engine
> >     won’t reach that conclusion until it actually goes through the
> >     motions of checking.
> >
> > So, by the time `:` is first checked, the `\w+`
> >     will have marched to the end of the string. This results in a lot of
> >     states — one `skip me` state for each match of `\w` by the plus
> >     (except the first, since plus requires one match). When then checked
> >     at the end of the string, `:` fails, so the regex engine backtracks to
> >     the most recently saved state:
>
> [image]
>
> > at
> >     which point the `:` fails again, this time trying to match `t`. This
> >     backtrack-test fail cycle happens all the way back to the oldest state:
>
> [image]
>
> > After the attempt from the final state
> >     fails, overall failure can finally be announced.
> >     All that backtracking is a lot of work that after just a glance we
> >     know to be unnecessary. If the colon can’t match after the last
> >     letter, it certainly can’t match one of the letters the `+` is forced
> >     to give up!
> >
> > So, knowing that none of the states left by `\w+`, once
> >     it’s finished, could possibly lead to a match, we can save the regex
> >     engine the trouble of checking them: `^(?>\w+):`. By adding the atomic
> >     grouping, we use our global knowledge of the regex to enhance the
> >     local working of `\w+` by having its saved states (which we know to be
> >     useless) thrown away. If there is a match, the atomic grouping won’t
> >     have mattered, but if there’s not to be a match, having thrown away
> >     the useless states lets the regex come to that conclusion more
> >     quickly.

---

I tried these regex **[here](https://regex101.com/)**. It took 4 steps for `^\w+:` and 6 steps for `^(?>\w+):` ***(with internal engine optimization disabled)***

---

**My Questions**

1. In the second paragraph from above section, it is mentioned that

> > So, by the time `:` is first checked, the `\w+` will have marched to the end of the string. This results in a lot of states — one skip me state for each match of `\w` by the plus (except the first, since plus requires one match).When then checked
> >     at the end of the string, `:` fails, so the regex engine backtracks to
> >     the most recently saved state:
>
> [image]
>
> > at
> >     which point the `:` fails again, this time trying to match `t`. This
> >     backtrack-test fail cycle happens all the way back to the oldest state:
>
> [image]

but on **[this](https://regex101.com/)** site, I see no backtracking. Why?

*Is there some optimization going on inside(even after it is disabled)?*

2. Can the number of steps taken by a regex decide whether one regex is having good performance over other regex?

Comment: its only useful if you have multiple patterns in bracket and only when there is chance for unnessary backtracks

Comment: also \w+ can match Subject and no backtracking needed, put non matchable char after Subject

Comment: @YOU can you explain a bit or write an answer?

Comment: I hope someone should come up with good explanation, I dont have much comprehension skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger on that site seems to gloss over the details of backtracking.  RegexBuddy does a better job.  Here's what it shows for `^\w+:`

[image: Normal (greedy)]

After `\w+` consumes all the letters, it tries to match `:` and fails.  Then it gives back one character, tries the `:` again, and fails again.  And so on, until there's nothing left to give back.  Fifteen steps total.  Now look at the atomic version (`^(?>\w+):`):

[image: Atomic]

After failing to match the `:` the first time, it gives back all the letters at once, as if they were one character.  A total of five steps, and two of those are entering and leaving the group.  And using a possessive quantifier (`^\w++:`) eliminates even those:

[image: Possessive]

As for your second question, yes, the number-of-steps metric from regex debuggers is useful, especially if you're just learning regexes.  Every regex flavor has at least a few optimizations that allow even badly written regexes to perform adequately, but a debugger (especially a flavor-neutral one like RegexBuddy's) makes it obvious when you're doing something wrong.

Comment: that pretty much answers my questions..one thing that I am curious to know in atomic group is **_why is there one more attempt of matching :_**  ?

Comment: Actually, I got that wrong.  There's no reason to try matching the colon at the beginning, any more than there is with the other two regexes.  The possessive version shows the essential steps: (1) start anchor, (2) letters, (3) colon, fail.  That extra `backtrack` threw me; I'll fix it.

Comment: ok..but then another question arises :- why the engine backtracks for the second time in atomic group?

Comment: I did some research: line 1 is `^` succeeding, line 2 is `\w+` succeeding, line 3 is the enclosing group succeeding, and line 4 is `:` failing, but I'm still not sure what line 5 represents.  It isn't really backtracking, because that part of the regex wasn't optional and it did succeed.  But whenever a match fails, the debugger shows an extra `backtrack` step for every group (capturing, non-capturing, atomic...anything but lookarounds).

Comment: yeah, that seems to be one good reason..thanks for your time and giving a well researched answer

Comment: If you wonder why there are more steps with the atomic group on regex101, it's pretty much because it gets the steps from the `PCRE_AUTO_CALLOUT` feature of PCRE, which invokes a callback function at each step of matching. Backtracking is just inferred from the pattern position at each callback. Oh, and *disable internal engine optimizations* adds `PCRE_NO_START_OPTIMIZE | PCRE_NO_AUTO_POSSESS` to the mix. Startup optimization is what makes the match fail outright, since the engine identified `:` as a required character, and auto possessification turned your pattern into `^\w++:` automatically